# Drone Cron Job Not Firing

Tags: cron, drone.io

I've created a cron job in Drone CI using the following command

`drone cron add --branch master "foo/bar" "every-5-mins" "0 */5 * * * *"`

And when I look in the UI, I can see the cron job has been created. However, it doesn't fire, even though I have it defined in my drone yaml file.

```
- name: cron-job
  pull: if-not-exists
  image: foo-image
  commands:
    - *random
    - echo "I am testing a cron job"
  when: &cron-demo
    event:
      - cron
    cron:
      - every-5-mins
```

Does something else need to be done to get it to work on schedule?

And also, is there a way to manually trigger a cron job? I can't seem to find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find this helpful.

`https://docs.drone.io/api/cron/cron_trigger/`

Basically, what you need is something like this.

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $DRONE_TOKEN" "$DRONE_SERVER/api/repos/foo/bar/cron/every-5-mins"
```